# Уменьшение потребляемой памяти при возвращаемом значении функции

Tags: c++

У меня есть вот такой метод класса

```
class IOManager {
    public:
        std::vector<std::string> getWordsFromString(std::string line) {
            std::vector<std::string> StringVect;
            //code
            return StringVect;
        }
    };
```

И он используется в дочернем классе так:

```
class ConsolIOManager : public IOManager {
    public:
    void SetHashTable(IOManager *obj, std::unordered_map<ull, std::string>& HashTable) override {
        for (auto &It : obj->getWordsFromString(obj->getText())) {
                //code
        }
    }
}
```

Как лучше всего в данном случае **возвращать вектор?** По ссылке или как в текущем коде копируя?

Comment: Если это C++17, то никакого копирования при возврате вектора тут нет. А вот принимать строку лучше по ссылке

Comment: @VTT почему? В с++17 есть какие-то изменения в vector?

Comment: Нет, в С++ были радикально переработаны правила инициализации и оптимизации возвращаемых значений. Теперь при возвращении переменной по значению, как в данном случае, не происходит ни копирования, ни перемещения.

Comment: С другой стороны, если вызывающая сторона может переиспользовать вектор, то имеет смысл принимать поссылке чтобы не перевыделять каждый раз место в векторе.

Comment: @VTT Нет, вектор не переписывается, так что, судя по всему, не стоит принимать по ссылке. Иду читать о С++17, спасибо

Comment: Так а как вы собирались возвращать его по ссылке? У вас же данные лежат в локальной переменной.

Comment: @AnT передать в параметрах по ссылке пустой вектор как вариант